# questions re migration antlr3 to antlr4 (apache pig) (2)

Tags: antlr4

I have a question about Apache Pig antlr3/antlr4 migration.

Original parser is QueryParser.g [here](https://github.com/apache/pig/tree/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/parser)

Two parts:

(1) "tokens {}" section syntax changed?

";" replaced by ","

Many errors of following pattern:

```
error(50): QueryParser.g4:37:9: syntax error: mismatched input ';' expecting RBRACE

parser code section here:

     35 
     36 tokens {
     37     QUERY;
     38     STATEMENT;
     39     FUNC;
     40     FUNC_REF;
     41     FUNC_EVAL;
 ....
```

(2)  getting error on grammar snippet below - there are actually many errors of this type, so i conclude that the punctuation between antlr3 and antlr4 must have changed - is this true? is there a summary of

```
query : statement* EOF -> ^( QUERY statement* )
;
```

the error is:

```
error(50): QueryParser.g4:10:23: syntax error: '->' came as a complete surprise to me while looking for rule element
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove the `tokens { ... }` from the parser grammar and add the following to your parser grammar (if you haven't done so already):

```
options {
  tokenVocab=QueryLexer;
  // output=AST;          <-- remove this
  // backtrack=false;     <-- remove this
}
```

2. remove `->` and everything after it (stop at the first `|` or `;`)

E.g.:

```
r
 : some rule    -> ^(SOME_TOKEN some rule)
 | another rule -> ^(ANOTHER_TOKEN another rule)
 ;
```

becomes:

```
r
 : some rule
 | another rule
 ;
```

The `-> ^( ... )` are tree-rewrite rules, which are not supported by v4. Most of the tokens defined in `tokens { ... }`, like `SOME_TOKEN` and `ANOTHER_TOKEN` are only used in these rewrite rules and could therefor be removed in point 1.

Comment: Thanks, i re-wrote the initial description to make it clearer, no further comment at this time, thnx again, mr

Comment: The options section has the following attributes:

options {
    tokenVocab=QueryLexer;
    output=AST;
    backtrack=false; // greatly slows down parsing!
}

tokenVocab is ok per you comment

i am thinking that the AST output and backtracking can also be removed, ??

Comment: @MarkRostron yes, both `output` and `backtrack` must be removed